# Paste Restriction in Textbox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, numeric

I have done the `textbox.shortcut= false` so I have restricted to copy and paste in the `textbox`. But I want to paste only numeric value (here I have also restricted in `key_press` that only numeric value will be put) but totally paste are not functioning, I want to paste only numeric value. How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe you should use NumericUpDown control instead

Answer (score 2):

I would handle that in the [`TextChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.textboxbase.textchanged.aspx) event.
That would catch paste, drag'n drop and all other possible scenarios.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trapping the keypress, you could check for Ctrl-V and check the clipboard contents using something like

```
   IDataObject clipData = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
   string data = (string)clipData.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Text);
```

You can then check (this.Text + data) to see if it is acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

If you build your own control based on the textbox you can override the WndProc event of the textbox:

```
    #region -- WndProc(ref Message m) Event Handler --
    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == WM_PASTE)
        {
            //your code here
        }
    }
    #endregion
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This in  the KeyDown Event

```
 Public Sub TextBoxNumeric_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As KeyEventArgs)
    Try
        ' Allow navigation keyboard arrows
        If fAllowNavigationArrows(e) Then

            ' Handle pasted Text
            If e.Control AndAlso e.KeyCode = Keys.V Then
                Dim strInput As String = Clipboard.GetText()
                Dim strOutput As String = ""
                Dim intStart As Integer
                Dim strNewTxt As String

                e.SuppressKeyPress = True

                ' Preview paste data (removing non-number characters)
                For intI As Integer = 0 To strInput.Length - 1
                    If Char.IsDigit(strInput(intI)) Or (strInput(intI) = "." And strOutput.Length > 0 And strOutput.IndexOf(".") < 0) Then
                        strOutput += strInput(intI).ToString()
                    End If
                Next

                ' Select TextBox Object
                With DirectCast(sender, TextBox)

                    .SelectAll()
                    intStart = .SelectionStart
                    strNewTxt = .Text
                    strNewTxt = strNewTxt.Remove(.SelectionStart, .SelectionLength)

                    ' Remove selected text
                    strNewTxt = strNewTxt.Insert(.SelectionStart, strOutput)

                    ' Paste
                    .Text = strNewTxt
                    .SelectionStart = intStart + strOutput.Length

                End With

            End If

        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw ex
    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use onchange event and every time when text is changed, try to parse it excluding every character that is not a number?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the MaskedTextBox control and set the mask to #####, for example, then you can copy a value like a123b and paste it into the masked edit control and it will only paste 123.